# Installing ESXi on vmware virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualhost, virtualization, esxi

I'm trying to install ESXi 5.5 on a vmware virtual machine (host os is windows 7 64 bit).

The virtuall machine successfully boot from the ISO file and strats installation, but later on I recieve an error that no network addapted is detected.

My virtual network adapter is set to as NAT (I tried the bridge and host-only options as well).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when installing ESXI natively on a computer. The problem is that the regular EXSi .ISO file supports a limited amount of network adapters - you can check whether or not your hardware is supported through this link:
http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php

To fix this, you need to download your drivers and insert them in to the ESXi .ISO image using the ESXi Boot Customiser tool (http://www.v-front.de/p/esxi-customizer.html).

All you need to do is select the .iso image, your drivers, and merge them with the tool.

All the best!